# Rest/_api Sharepoint 2013 get list of filters (refiners)

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Hi guys i've been looking for an api for sharepoint2013 i'm using Rest/api, where i could return the list of filters based on a keyword but i could not find any

Best i could find is

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nadeemis/2012/08/24/sharepoint-2013-search-rest-api/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx

but i'm not interested in filtering results but get the list of filters based on a result. any ideas, links? would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So i could not find what i was looking for, but anyway i am close enough. So this is what i did, i have a string of filters separated by "," ( would have wanted to get filters without explicit specifying them, in my case the filters are document filters)

var _filters = "filter_A,filter_B,...";

and i do a simple ajax request as following, also since i was requesting from a different app domain i had to enable CORS in the application for which i wanted to get the resources (i've configured the web.config file to allow my application to make get requests)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://requestedwebsite/_api/search/query?querytext=%27" + $("#filtervalue").val() + "%27&refiners=%27" + _filters + "%27",
    method: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
    },
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    crossDomain: true,
    error: function (a, b, c) { },
    success: function (data) {
        var _object = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RefinementResults.Refiners;
        var results = _object.results; //--> array, process it 

        }
    }
});
```

You can play with data.d object see what is there what you need from it.
$("#filtervalue").val() just take the value from an input type='text'

hopefully it will help someone whom as myself has to deal with this mess called sharepoint and has no idea if what is being done is ok.